# Install opera on rpi?

Tags: internet, web

I think that all the other browsers are kind of, um, Not Private. Though Firefox is good I don't like it. I would rather use Opera instead. I tried installing it through APT (`sudo apt install opera`) ad found out it is not in the repositories. I tried the one from https://opera.com for linux x86, and, it didn't work. So, how do I install Opera on my RPi 4 4G?

Comment: Closest I know of is Vivaldi - co-founder was involved in Opera at the start.  Not an answer hence the comment.

Comment: @Andrew, I want to use Opera, not Vivaldi. I like opera's vpn feature.

Comment: `for linux x64` ... raspberry pi is `arm` so of course x64 (i.e AMD/Intel) won't work ... looks like the good people at Opera don't make 32 bit arm binaries - nor can you compile it from source, so the simple answer is ... no Opera for you

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll try using box x86.